Monazite-(Ce): Non-integer ratios of substitutable elements
I've been looking at EDS data for monazite-(Ce):



And I noticed that (at the O=4 column) the ratios of substitutable elements are not integers. I thought that it was because of measurement errors, but the second and third data has values of 0.8656 and 0.7892 which doesn't seem like errors at all.
Is there a reason why they have non-integer ratios?
My guess is that:
because the samples were taken from a small portion of the rock itself, some unit cells of monazite were partially separated resulting in a non-integer ratio.
Am I correct?
Please add references for answers.
